# Is there a way to force a map reload/refresh in openlayers 5?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

Using openlayers 5, I'm getting an issue where geometry persists on the map after deleting it - seems like the map isn't updating properly. Is there a way to force an update / refresh of the map and its features? Can't find anything related to that in the documentation.

Tried using `map.render()` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Calling `.getFeatures()` on my VectorSource object shows that the geometry/object is not in the features list, but it still appears on the map on my page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[EDIT]
As noted in the OpenLayers [changelog](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/changelog/upgrade-notes.md#change-of-the-behavior-of-the-vector-sources-clear-and-refresh-methods) v6.0.0 you have now to call:

```js
layer.changed()
```

---

Try to [refresh](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Source-Source.html#refresh) your source:

```
layer.getSource().refresh();
```

Or do this for all layers:

```
map.getLayers().forEach(layer => layer.getSource().refresh());
```

If this still does not work:

Assuming your layer is the first layer, try `console.log(map.getLayers()[0].getFeatures());`. Are the deleted features logged? If so, it might be a reference problem.

Comment: What I'm actually doing is removing a layer from my map, but it's still showing on the map. If I look on the console and call map.getLayers, it shows that the layer is no longer inside the map but I'm still seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this is an old question. If you're using TypeScript:

```
import Vector from "ol/layer/Vector";

map?.getAllLayers().forEach((layer) => {
      if (layer instanceof Vector) {
        layer.getSource()?.refresh();
      }
  });
```